# Multiple font family values in WPF

Tags: wpf, font-family

To ensure which font will be used as a fallback if the primary font is not available on the user's OS.

Is it possible to specify multiple font family values in WPF, similar to CSS?

For instance:

```css
font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can: `FontFamily = "Times New Roman, Georgia, Serif"`:

Extract from the XAML values of `TextBlock.FontFamily` property [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontfamily?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#xaml-values):

> *`fontFamilyNamesList`
>
> A string specifying multiple font family names, each separated by a comma (any white space following a comma is ignored). The first font family specified serves as the primary font family; subsequent font families serve as fallback families to be used in cases where the primary font family is unavailable or not applicable. For example, `"Arial, Century Gothic"` specifies Arial as the primary font family, with Century Gothic as the fallback font family.*

Example, Georgia doesn't contains chinese font.

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock FontSize = "20" FontFamily = "Georgia">English 中文</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock FontSize = "20" FontFamily = "Georgia, FangSong">English 中文</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock FontSize = "20" FontFamily = "FangSong">English 中文</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]